# Can't include ruby modules correctly

Tags: ruby

I'm kinda new to Ruby, so I'm not even sure if what I'm doing is best practice. Right now I am trying to define a function *import* that resides in a module on something.rb:
    require 'rexml/document'

```
module MyModule
    def import(file)
        Document.new(File.new(file))
    end
end
```

I have another file somethingelse.rb that calls on file something.rb that will use function *import*
    require 'something.rb'

```
class MyClass
    include MyModule
    def initialize(file)
        @myFile = import(file)
    end
end
```

The problem only arises when I try to import the module from another file. When I use the module in the same file, everything works according to what you'd expect. The errors I get are:

```
usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rexml/dtd/elementdecl.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant PATTERN_RE
XMLTest.rb:9: uninitialized constant MyModule (NameError)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to require the other file you're trying to load in your first file, Ruby won't do that for you automatically. So if your module is in a file named "something.rb":

```
require "something"

class MyClass
  include MyModule
  def initialize(file)
    @myFile = import(file)
  end
end
```

Comment: Turns our rexml didn't like the way I was naming my files. The real name I used was "XMLParser.rb" so it got mad when I called:
    require "XMLParser.rb"
Thanks for helping! =]

Answer (score 0):

try changing your rexml require to require_once.

So:

```
require_once 'rexml/document'
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve any problem. When I move the rexml require to somethingelse.rb, that error seems to go away. My main concern is why the interpreter thinks MyModule is an undefined constant?

Comment: Oh, I didn't pay close enough attention :(  I thought you were concerned about the 'already initialized constant' line and totally missed that you didn't require the module in the file that included it.

Answer (score 0):

you can you use require_relative to import the file that has your module
use include to add the module in the class to access the module

```
   class MyClass
   include somethingModuleName
   end
```